# Can limits of a sequence $|s_n-s|$ be written in reverse as $|s-s_n|$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was wondering if for the definition of a limit I could  write it in reverse and for it to still be valid:

Say $\lim(s_n) = s$ then can i write $|s_n-s|< e$ or $|s-s_n|< e$ at my discretion.

I know the first is correct but the second greatly simplifies a proof for me

Comment: Absolute value of any real number and it's negative are the same.

Comment: Yes; $y=\operatorname{abs} x$ is an even function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $|s_n-s|=|-1(s-s_n)|=|-1||s-s_n| = |s-s_n|$.

Comment: For a question like this your second equality may be not obvious either for the asker. But it can be proven easily I guess.

Comment: @DerekLuna I chose this method because norms are absolutely homogeneous and so this method generalizes easily to vector spaces.